# Detect event: system is going to sleep on every OS

Tags: java, java-native-interface, jna

I'm creating application in `Java` which needs catch when system is going to sleep/hibernate mode. I know there is `Java Native Access`, where I can catch event on Windows, but I need solution for MacOS and Linux as well. I have seen method with counting time and compare it with current time:

```
            while (true) {
                long sleepTil = System.currentTimeMillis() + pause + error;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(pause);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
                if (System.currentTimeMillis() > sleepTil) {
                    log.info("System was suspended");
                } else {
                    log.info("System was not suspended.");
                }
            }
```

but it works AFTER sleep, not before.

Comment: Pass a [SystemSleepListener](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/desktop/SystemSleepListener.html) to [Desktop.addAppEventListener](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Desktop.html#addAppEventListener%28java.awt.desktop.SystemEventListener%29).

Comment: JNA works for Mac and Linux but you need to tell us what commands on those OS's you're trying to implement.